# Error in installing ursa - error C2660: 'v8::String::Utf8Length': function does n ot take 0 arguments

Tags: node.js, npm, encryption, npm-install

I am trying to install ursa package to my react js project for encryption/decryption. But I am having below error in the installation.

My node versions: 12.13.0

My NPM version: 6.12.0

```
109 warn @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
110 warn @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
111 warn @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
112 warn tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
113 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
114 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
115 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
115 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
115 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
115 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
116 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
117 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
118 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
118 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
118 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
118 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
119 verbose stack Error: ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
119 verbose stack Exit status 1
119 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
119 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
119 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
119 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
119 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
119 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
120 verbose pkgid ursa@0.9.4
121 verbose cwd D:\xampp\htdocs\yoface
122 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
123 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "ursa"
124 verbose node v12.13.0
125 verbose npm  v6.12.0
126 error code ELIFECYCLE
127 error errno 1
128 error ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
128 error Exit status 1
129 error Failed at the ursa@0.9.4 install script.
129 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
130 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help me in this concern.